# a question about orthogonal subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure why the following statement is true because it seems ambiguous.

```
A line through the origin and the whole plane are never orthogonal subspaces.
```

I am following the definition here: Subspace S is orthogonal to subspace T means: every vector in S is orthogonal to every vector in T.

Then I am assuming for one case that in 3D the whole plane is the xy plane, and if the line is the z axis, then would z and the xy plane be orthogonal subspaces? 
In addition, please state briefly why the statement is true.

Comment: Presumably the ambient space in the quote **was** the plane?

Comment: You are correct. The vertical $z$-axis is the orthogonal subspace to the $x$-$y$ plane even though the $z$-axis passes through the origin. I suspect that the book is referring to $\mathbb{R}^2$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @DanielApsley, yes, I'll assume in R<sup>2</sup> this is correct.